# Why can't I copy paste this text in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim

When even i try to copy paste this text in vim it put half of it in the command line and half in text editor main window

This is the text

`sub(/;;/," ",$0)`

How can i copy paste that

Comment: You could tap right click once, make sure you're in insert mode

Comment: I have done that and i am in insert mode as well. i think the problem is with two semicolons together , if i change that then it works ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you paste in console Vim (not GVIM), Vim cannot detect whether what you've pasted is typed by you or an actual paste. Therefore, any (insert mode) mappings will apply. You probably have a mapping (maybe `;;`?) that leaves insert mode, and that is triggered during the paste, wreaking havoc.

There are two ways to prevent that:

Either paste in normal mode via `"*p` (active selection) or `"+p` (system clipboard), provided that Vim is able to interact with them.

Or, set the `'pastetoggle'` option, e.g.

```
:set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

and then press <kbd>F2</kbd> (in insert mode) before pasting (note how the mode changes to `-- INSERT (paste) --`, and again after it. This way, you explicitly tell Vim "the next characters aren't typed by me, treat them literally".

If this manual management is too much of a hassle for you, you can alternatively use graphical GVIM.

Comment: the funny thing is that gvim shows right in the menu that Paste is just `"+gP` -- that's how i first found out about the system clipboard buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which way you're copying and pasting (i.e. from an Xorg window (like gnome-terminal) to vim or vice-versa). Let's assume you want to copy and paste from an Xorg window into your vim window. There are a few ways to do it:

1. Select the text to copy using the mouse, put vim into insert mode, then press the middle mouse button.
2. If you are using vim with X support in a console (often started by typeing vimx) then you can select the text to copy using the mouse, then in the vimx window press `"*p`. The text selected by the mouse is placed in the `*` register.
3. If you are using vim with X support in a console (started by typing vimx) then you can select the text to copy using the mouse, right click the mouse, choose menu item `Copy` and then in the vimx window hit `"+p` to paste. In this case, because you used the right click menu item to copy, the text was placed in the in the `+` register.

Items 2 and 3 above also work when using gvim.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make sure you're in insert mode and copy the code snippet with ctrl+v on the keyboard and then left click to the vim window to put it back in focus, then tap right click once and your text should paste in.  I just tested this to make sure and it worked on CentOS 6.3 at least.

Answer (score 0):

In vim you have modes, to enter text you have to be in insert mode. Press `i` (before current char) or `a` (after current char) before pasting your text.

If you don't go into insert mode, the first char `s` will erase the current char and enter insert mode putting `ub(/;;/," ",$0)` on your file.

Press `ESC` to leave the insert mode.

Also if you happen to have a shared clipboard with your GUI pressing `p` will paste.

To have a shared clipboard on OSX insert `set clipboard=unnamed` in your `~/.vimrc` file.